# Split a string in java into two parts

Tags: java

I want to split a string based on a substring, and get the first part. Example below.

**Input:**

```
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[12]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]
```

**Ouptut:** splitted at [12]

```
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[12]
```

I wrote this code :

```
String path1 = "body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[12]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]"
String result;
if(path1.contains("[12]")){
                System.out.println("yes");
                result = path1.split("[12]")[0];
                System.out.println(result);
            }
```

but I got result like this :

```
body/div[
```

Comment: @kivik94: It would be better to mark the best answer as accepted.

Comment: @JadChahine done !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[` character is interpreted as a special regex character so you should escape it by adding `\\`

So replace

```
 result = path1.split("[12]")[0];
```

By

```
 result = path1.split("\\[12]")[0];
```

#### Output:

```
yes
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li
```

Comment: Output would be preferable as text. It's good that you included it though.

Comment: This must be duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

```
String result = path1.substring(0, path1.indexOf("li[12]") + 6);
```

Comment: Be careful, this solution does not exactly produce the required output. As noted by an answer below, you would have to use `path.indexOf("li[12]") + 6`. Apart from that, do you want to search for `li[12]` or just for `[12]`?

Comment: @Beethoven No, that is _wrong_.  [String.indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) does _not_ accept regex, it only takes strings.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Where did I say, that `indexOf` accepts regex?

Comment: @Beethoven I think he edited his question since when I first answered.

Answer (score 4):

The `split` method accepts regular expressions. The regular expression `[12]` matches one character which is either `1` or `2` and therefore splits the string between each `1` or `2`. A better solution is to search for the occurrence of `[12]` directly:

```
int indexOf12 = path1.indexOf("[12]");
if(indexOf12 != -1)
{
     System.out.println("yes");
     String result = path1.substring(0, indexOf12 + 4);
     System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

need to add [12] after substring so +6 in result

```
String result = path1.substring(0, path1.indexOf("li[12]")+6);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem. Thing is you have to provide Regex for split. Not only string.

```
String path1 = "body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[12]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]";
        String result;
        if(path1.contains("[12]")){
            System.out.println("yes");
            result = path1.split("\\[12\\]")[0];
            System.out.println(result+"[12]");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of RegEx specific approach:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*\\[12\\])")
            .matcher("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[12]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]");
```

**Output**

```
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[12]
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List < String > allMatches = new ArrayList < String > ();

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*\\[12\\])")
            .matcher("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[12]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]");

        while (m.find())
            allMatches.add(m.group(1));

        for (String match: allMatches)
            System.out.println(match);
    }

}
```